# How to assign a record type to a profile

Tags: profile, record-type, configuration

I have been following this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_recordtype.htm) to see how I can assign a Task record type I created for a profile I have. However, the instructions say "Select a profile. The record types available for that profile are listed in the Record Type Settings section", but I cannot find the "Record Type Settings section". The closest thing there is is:

> Object Settings
>
> Permissions to access objects and fields, and settings
> that specify which record types, page layouts, and tabs are visible

But even in there I cannot find the record type I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick an object to assign record types for. So, Setup > Profiles > *Profile Name* > Object Settings > *Object Name* > Edit. Note that this is only true if you have the Enhanced Profile Editor. The notes you're looking at are written for the "classic" editor, which presented all options on a single page.

[image: Edit Object Settings Example]

Classic view:

[image: Classic View Header]

...

[image: Classic Record Types]